# JFrame window doesn't show up?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm currently building a space invader style game in Java. Its the first I do, so I'm trying to make sense of it. The main requirement is that it runs on desktop.

Now I'm trying to use jFrame for this, but it isn't letting me do what I want to do. When I run my app, it does show a java "app" running in my dock (I run OSX), but the actual jFrame window doesn't show up.

This is how I create the window:

```
public GildeInvaders() {
    add(new Panel());
    setTitle("Gilde Opleidingen Space Invaders");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500, 500);
    //setSize(GildeInvaders.getConfiguration().getInt("game.width"), 

    GildeInvaders.getConfiguration().getInt("game.height"));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    new GildeInvaders();
}
```

The `Panel` I'm initiating is an instance of jPanel, which I think is the right approach:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    // Lot of variables here


    public Panel() {
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);
        dimension = new Dimension(GildeInvaders.getConfiguration().getInt("game.width"), GildeInvaders.getConfiguration().getInt("game.height"));
        setBackground(Color.black);
        this.initiate();
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
    }
```

All the variables, the dimensions etc. are defined.

I thought it could be that some variables weren't defined, or I didn't set it to visible, but that appears to be wrong.

How can it be that this window isn't showing up? Did I misread some articles and docs?

Thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me (after cutting out your Game-specific stuff of course).

Maybe it is a Threading-Problem.
You could try calling your JFrames constructor this way:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new GildeInvaders();        
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JPanel is a Swing component and every Swing component must have at least one top-level container. You should use JFrame which is a top-level container to create a frame and to that you can add Swing components like JPanel. To make the frame appear you should use SwingUtilites.invokeLater() method so that it is asynchronously executed on the AWT event dispatching thread. Here is a great example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FrameDemoProject/src/components/FrameDemo.java

Comment: Based on the use of `setDefaultCloseOperation` in `GildeInvaders`, I'd say that it's a top level container...

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are absolutely right, my mistake.